# Can't create new project using Angular IDE

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular programming and just recently installed the Angular IDE editor (which appears to be a set of plugins for Eclipse.  I downloaded from https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/).

Anyhow, I tried to create a new project and after clicking through a short new project wizard, which has a dialog that says it will initialize my project with the following commands:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.6.5
ng new Foo --skip-git
npm install --save-dev angular-ide
```

the setup fails with an error and the terminal displays

```
Downloading and extracting NPM 5.6.0...
Input is not in the .gz format
```

I run into similar error message if I try to run the project.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.  I'm running this on windows 10.  Is there something I need to configure to get Angular IDE to work?

---

After using the below suggestion for the 'Use system installtion' I was able to get further, but am now encountering a new error:

```
...
CREATE Angular/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (299 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE Angular/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"w
in32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path C:\Users\kitfox\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\Angular\node_modules\.bin\ng
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\kitfox\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\Angular\node_modules\.bin\ng'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\kitfox\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\Angular\node_modules\.bin\ng'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\kitfox\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\Angular\node_modules\.bin\ng'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\kitfox\\Workspaces\\Angular IDE 2017 CI\\Angular\\node_modules\\.bin\\ng' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'C:\\Users\\kitfox\\Workspaces\\Angular IDE 2017 CI\\Angular\\node_modules\\.
bin\\ng\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
```

Comment: Angular IDE is NOT the official IDE, I recommend you to use Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same error **Input is not in the .gz format**, couldn't find solution in genuitech forums.

how I fixed this:

1. download and install node.js **9.4.0** (https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/).
2. launch Angular IDE, create a new project, select use system installations

[image: New Angular Project]

3. right-click project (below Angular CLI, Servers tab), select properties to edit launch configuration. select Node 9.4.0 (*it may be listed as Global Node.js*)
4. start server, http://localhost:4200/

[image]

Comment: That helped - I was able to get further, but now I'm getting a new error.

Comment: It's kinda long.  Posted it in the main question above.